# shutil.copy2 - Behaviour with different file systems and pseudo files

Tags: python, shutil

I have written a small script to synchronize two directories. The script allows to sync certain file types and allows file comparison by checksum or date.
After comparison a list of files that should be copied is given to a file copy procedure that makes use of the **shutil.copy2()** module.
In various test runs I found a strange behaviour of shutil.copy2 and I do not have a workaround:

First:
If the source is an ext3 volume and the target is fat32 (memory stick) shutil raises an error.
I think it is because shutil.copy2 tries to copy the metadata as well and this is not supported by fat32. But I do not know how to catch this error with a try: except: statement.

Second:
The second Problem is even more difficult. Both source and target are ext3 volumes. On the source there are some backups of a complete Linux directory tree. When my utility tries to synchronize these directory trees, the script runs in an endless loop until my system partition runs out of space.
I tried to fix this behaviour and use the stat module to check if the source file is a regular file before starting the copy process but it does not help. The file in question with the strange behaviour is /proc/661/fd/3. Maybe there are some more, but I cannot test that because my system freezes because of the memory consumption while trying to copy this file.

I tried to find a solution for these two problems for several day now and I hope that the skilled programmers around her can support me.

Thanks for any help.

Here the code of my filecopy procedure:

```
def _filecopy(file_list, from_dir, to_dir, overwrt):
print "Files and directories will be processed: "
for file_tupel in file_list:
    source_file_name = from_dir + file_tupel[1] + file_tupel[0]
    try:
        filemode = os.stat(source_file_name).st_mode
    except:
        filemode = 33205 
    if S_ISREG(filemode):
        target_dir_name = to_dir + file_tupel[1]
        if not os.path.isdir(target_dir_name):
            print "Create directory " + target_dir_name
            _mkdir(target_dir_name)
        target_file_name = target_dir_name + file_tupel[0]
        if os.path.isfile(target_file_name) and overwrt == "mark":
            name_appendix = "_marked_by_sync_as_different_on_" + time.strftime("%a_%d_%b_%Y_%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
            if target_file_name.find(".") == -1:
                new_target_file_name = target_file_name + name_appendix
                new_source_file_name = source_file_name + name_appendix
            else:
                new_target_file_prefix = target_file_name.rpartition(".")[0]
                new_target_file_extension = target_file_name.rpartition(".")[2]
                new_target_file_name = new_target_file_prefix + name_appendix + "." + new_target_file_extension
                new_source_file_prefix = source_file_name.rpartition(".")[0]
                new_source_file_name = new_source_file_prefix + name_appendix + "." + new_target_file_extension
            print "Rename file " + target_file_name + " in " + new_target_file_name
            os.rename(target_file_name, new_target_file_name)
            print "Copy file " + new_target_file_name + " to " + new_source_file_name
            try:
                shutil.copy2(new_target_file_name, new_source_file_name)
            except:
                print "Could not copy " + new_target_file_name + " to " + new_source_file_name
        print "Copy file " + source_file_name + " to " + target_file_name
        try:
            shutil.copy2(source_file_name, target_file_name)
        except:
            print "Could not copy " + source_file_name + " to " + target_file_name
    else:
        print source_file_name + " seems to be no regular file and will not be copied."
```

After following the hint from Answer No. 1 the shutil,copy2 statements changes to:

```
    shutil.copyfile(source_file_name, target_file_name)
    try:
        #try to set permission bits
        shutil.copymode(new_target_file_name, new_source_file_name)
    except:
        print "Permission bits could not be copied"
    try:
        #try to copy metadata
        shutil.copystat(new_target_file_name, new_source_file_name)
    except:
        print "Metadata could not be copied"
```

Comment: Please post the full tracebacks for both errors.

Comment: For the /proc error there is no message. The system just freezes.

Comment: The traceback for the file system error is: File "/home/piet/Desktop/server_disk_backup/music kopieren/pietsync.py", line 260, in _filecopy shutil.copy2(new_target_file_name, new_source_file_name) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_target_file_name' referenced before assignmen

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.copy2()` is simply `shutil.copy()` followed by `shutil.copystat()`. To solve your first problem, you might want to copy over the [source of `shutil.copy2()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py) and enclose the `copystat()` part in a try-except block. You should be able to figure out which exception to catch from the error traceback.

You probably don't want to copy the `/proc` filesystem at all. I'd just exclude this whenever you call your script.

Comment: My /proc problem: I try to keep my sync tool as universally usable as possible. So I dont want to exclude certain files or directories by name. Maybe there is another solution for the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Your solution for copying between different filesystems works if I use shutil.copyfile() instead of shutil.copy() or shutil.copy2(). But maybe there is a better way of doing this without raising an error for every file that is synchronized.